# How to set page view in PHPExcel as page layout?

Tags: php, layout, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to export Excel reports and I want to know if there is a way to set page view mood as page layout.

Comment: image for more explanation http://postimg.org/image/4txnl7aoz/

Answer (score 3):

Solved using this code:

```
$objPHPExcel->
    getActiveSheet()->
    getSheetView()->
    setView(PHPExcel_Worksheet_SheetView::SHEETVIEW_PAGE_LAYOUT);
```